# Compilation of the eclipse run-time kernel or vanilla eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'm trying to build eclipse from scratch. I could download eclipse e4 from CVS, which has 426 projects. After the automatic build, I got tens of broken project build. I tried to [fix some of them](http://prosseek.blogspot.com/2012/11/building-eclipse-source-base-and.html), but most of them are still broken including swt and jface.

Googling about eclipse architecture, I found that [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) points out that 
`With the exception of a small run-time kernel, everything in Eclipse is a plug-in.`

What projects in CVS are the run-time kernel? How many projects do I need to build `successfully` to get vanilla eclipse that is not a plugin but core eclipse? I mean what is the project that after the build I can execute `eclipse.exe` even though it has no plugin?

Any hints for building them would also be great.

Comment: This would be a better question for the Eclipse forums: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question to eclipse forum to get [some answers](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/989154/).

In short, this is the idea.

1. You need a launcher which is platform dependent:

   - http://eclipse.org/equinox/framework/
   - http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F
2. Then, you need OSGi/Equinox to be compiled

   - http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/documents/quickstart-framework.php

Once you have the launcher and OSGi, everything is a module on top of it.